# Why does composer create-project fail when requring a dev dependency, but succeed with --no-plugins flag?

Tags: composer-php

### Scenario

- Have an upstream project, `upstream/example` with dependency on `drupal/block_access:dev-1.x`. The project is based on https://github.com/pantheon-systems/example-drops-8-composer/
- This command fails at `block_access` with error "Not a git repository"

  - `composer create-project upstream/example new-project --stability=dev`
- But the same command with `--no-plugins` flag completes without any errors

  - `composer create-project upstream/example new-project --stability=dev --no-plugins`

### Full error message

```
  [RuntimeException]                                                                                                                              
  Failed to execute git checkout '1cd59ba6856c897afae2551feaa8e6b7f312489c' -- && git reset --hard '1cd59ba6856c897afae2551feaa8e6b7f312489c' --  

  fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

### Questions

Why is the original command failing?

What does no-plugins do exactly?

How can I identify the plugin that's causing this to fail, if that's indeed the culprit?

I'm still learning the deatils of composer -- any tips would be super helpful!

The full composer.json is here: https://pastebin.com/42ssDqc4

Comment: How does `composer create-project` fail? What exception/error-message do you face?

Comment: @NicolaiFröhlich updated OP with full error message